# How can I pass IDs from two different models to a new one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm currently trying to pass User_id and Event_id as params for Guest:

Right now in the console, I can create a new guest object using:

```
Guest.new(user_id: #, event_id: #)
```

After creating a guest object, I can call 'User.assited_events' to get all the events this user is assisting, same with events I can call 'Event.assitances' to gell all the users assisting this event.

I just want to figure out a way to submit the user_id and event_id from events#index.

I'm using a custom method called 'Assist' inside of Events Controller

```
def assist
    @guest = Guest.create(:user_id => User.find(session[:current_user_id]), :event_id => Event.find(params[:id]))

    respond_to do |format|
      if @guest.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'You are now assiting this event!' }
        format.json { head :no_content}
      else
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "An error happened you can't assist this event" }
        format.json { render json: @guest.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This the current line to link the assist_event_path at events#index

```
<td><%= link_to 'Assist', assist_event_path(event), method: :put, data: { confirm: 'Do you want to assist to this event?' } %></td>
```

The result in the server log is passing both ids but the Guest object is not created:

```
Processing by EventsController#assist as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"8nddKRZpYcgYDkfJIv/VXK8Os1FmW1oZ+zRIQUnLlE/dhgIA92chq++leqplfaB+bdqIZnCWlB0vPLRfuoHOGw==", "id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/events_controller.rb:65:in `assist'
  Event Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/events_controller.rb:65:in `assist'
```

User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events
  has_many :guests
  has_many :assisted_events, :through => :guests, :source => :event
end
```

Event model

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :guests
  has_many :assistances, :through => :guests, :source => :user
end
```

Guest model

```
class Guest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

routes file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :events do
     member do
        patch :assist
        put :assist
      end
  end
  resources :users

  root 'events#index'
end
```

EDIT ----

Events Controller

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /Events
  # GET /Events.json
  def index
    @events = Event.all
  end

  # GET /Events/1
  # GET /Events/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /Events/new
  def new
    @event = User.find(session[:current_user_id]).events.build
  end

  # GET /Events/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /Events
  # POST /Events.json
  def create
    @event = User.find(session[:current_user_id]).events.build(event_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /Events/1
  # PATCH/PUT /Events/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.update(event_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /Events/1
  # DELETE /Events/1.json
  def destroy
    @event.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to events_url, notice: 'Event was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def assist
    @guest = Guest.create(:user_id => User.find(session[:current_user_id]), :event_id => Event.find(params[:id]))

    respond_to do |format|
      if @guest.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'You are now assiting this event!' }
        format.json { head :no_content}
      else
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "An error happened you can't assist this event" }
        format.json { render json: @guest.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_event
      @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:title, :body)
    end
end
```

Events#Index file

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Events</h1>
<% if session[:current_user_id].is_a? Integer %>
  <h3>Current User ID: <%= session[:current_user_id] %></h3>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Create a new user', new_user_path  %>
<% end %>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @events.each do |event| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= event.title  %></td>
      <td><%= event.body  %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', event %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(event) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Assist', assist_event_path(event), method: :put, data: { confirm: 'Do you want to assist to this event?' } %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New event', new_event_path %>
```

Comment: Couple comments - Guest.create() fully creates a record, I don't know why you have 'if @guest.save' below that - it's already been saved, you're double-dipping the DB at that point.  And I don't know why you do User.find(session[:current_user_id] when all you want is the ID that you *already have!*. You don't need to search the DB for an ID that is stored in session or passed via params.

Comment: I tried with just the cookie session[:current_user_id] and it didn't recognize the ID, so only with User.find allowed me to get the ID from the user. Right now the user is just a cookie that I save directly from the browser. I was using the .create to try the function, I forgot to change it back to .new when I copy and pasted the code.

Comment: You should review the value of `current_user_id` because it sounds like you aren't using that the way you expect to be using it.  If User.find(1) works but current_user_id == 1 doesn't work, that sounds like you have a bug.

Comment: It works. As I said is just a cookie that saves the current user session which is only the user_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is kind of a guess since you didn't post any of your form except the link_to. I have no idea what variables you have passed to the `events#index` because you didn't post your controller code for that. That said you can pass any params you want with `link_to`.
*edit* OK, so it looks like user is in `session[:current_user_id]` so that is where the user id comes from...

**latest edit to simplify**

Add this route before your other routes to make sure it's at the top:

```
put '/assist' => 'events#assist'
```

Then in your form:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Assist', assist_path(event_id: event, user_id: session[:current_user_id]), method: :put, data: { confirm: 'Do you want to assist to this event?' } %></td>
```

Make sure your params are permitted in your strong parameters section.

```
# Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:title, :body, :event_id, :user_id)
end
```

*edit* cleaning up your controller code:

```
def assist
    @guest = Guest.new(:user_id => session[:current_user_id], :event_id => event_params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @guest.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'You are now assiting this event!' }
        format.json { head :no_content}
      else
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "An error happened you can't assist this event" }
        format.json { render json: @guest.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

You were passing the actual Event and User objects to create the @guest object. Also you were using the params, which means you weren't going through the event_params action. The purpose of the event_params action is to permit/deny so that someone can't submit params you don't want.

Comment: Thank you for the observation, I edited the post with the events#index HTML file and the events controller.

Comment: I'm getting this error: No route matches {:action=>"assist", :controller=>"events", :event_id=>1, :user_id=>1}, missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: That is because you don't have a route for the link_to you are using. On the command line do `rake routes` and look for the route that matches what you need. I'll edit my answer to a possible path. You are nesting paths, which can be convenient but sometimes overcomplicated when you nest three deep.

Comment: Actually that does look like the right path. Possibly just the permit needed in the params.

Comment: I made the corrections but still the same error. I verified the route and is the correct one for the method. Also, I tried with just Guest.new(event_params) and adding the :user_id and :event_id parameters but I got the same error again.

Comment: I don't know why you nested those routes in the first place. Add this to your routes: `post '/events/assist' => 'events#assist'`

Comment: I’m nesting the routes so I can have access to each event.id directly from the each function in events#index. If not then event object is not recognized and returns nil.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and still ask for an ID. Maybe there’s a better way to create the route, instead of nesting?

Comment: "asking for ID" could mean a million things. Has the error changed at all?

Comment: Try `events_assist_path(event), method: :put, data: { confirm: 'Do you want to assist to this event?' }` and see if you can at least get to the assist method in the controller.

Comment: Oh, I just saw that your wrote "instead of nesting". That route I gave you should NOT be nested in the other routes. It should be a stand alone route and I would put it before the other routes to troubleshoot it.

Comment: You should not need nesting to access `event.id` in the Events controller because you are passing it the events anyway.

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer with the latest info. Take a look.

Comment: " Couldn't find Event with 'id'=assist "

Comment: giving me just the error code is not helpful. I need to see the stack trace. Show me everything in the web console where it has the parameters hash.

Comment: Don't paste it here. Edit your question and add it to the bottom.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, I added a picture with the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212879/discussion-between-beartech-and-ghamtre).